# jQuery adding many options to a select kills chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, for-loop

I am trying to add around 500 options to a select using jQuery.
It runs a 500 times loop.

```
for( var i=0; i<ids.length;i++ ){
  $("#selectId').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + label + '</option>');
}
```

In `Mozilla Firefox` etc it works fine ( takes around 3 seconds ) but in `Goggle Chrome` the browser crashes after half a minute.

I put some logs to see how much time it needs, it starts with 1ms every loop and then it increases to ~1s ...

Any suggestions to make it more efficient?

Comment: Do you really need 500 options in one drop down? Anyway, you would have better to concatenate a string inside `for` loop and then append it to select element once loop is done or use HTML fragment

Comment: Search tool? I can't conceptualize ever needing 500 options in a drop down. Are you open to using a different interface?

Comment: build the options as a string (best with pushing to an array and then .join('') ), and then use `$('#selectId').html(options)`, or `document.getElementById('selectId').innerHTML = options`

Comment: Here use document fragment, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/n45j6e8w/

Comment: It works fine for me from both Firefox and Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/eacrst14/. Anyway you have an error with quotes in your example `$("#selectId')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two performance problems with your loop:

1. in each iteration, you're creating a new jQuery object and searching the DOM for #selectId
2. in each iteration, you're manipulating the DOM, adding one row.

Both of these have a cost on the performance. try:

```
var options = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  // first, populate an array with all the options as strings
  options.push('<option value="' + value + '">' + label + '</option>');
}
// then, join that array into a string and just .append or .html
$('#selectId').append(options.join(''));
// OR
$('#selectId').html(options.join(''));
```